# When exactly should I use parentheses for functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, es6-promise

Here is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/mkjh2ev5/192/):

```
let cleanRoom = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('Cleaned The Room');
  });
};

let removeGarbage = function(message) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(message + ' remove Garbage');
  });
};

let winIcecream = function(message) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve( message + ' won Icecream');
  });
};

Promise.all([cleanRoom, removeGarbage, winIcecream]). then(function(){
    console.log('all finished');
})

Promise.all([cleanRoom(), removeGarbage(), winIcecream()]). then(function(){
    console.log('all finished');
})
```

As you can see, both *(with and without parentheses)* return the same result. So is this right to say?

> You should use parentheses only when you want to pass something to the function. Otherwise no need to use it.

Comment: You use the parentheses to call the function and use its result. You don't use parentheses to pass the function itself around.

Comment: on the first `Promise.all` you passed function reference to the outer function block, in the second you passed the result of the outer function which happens to be a `Promise`.

Comment: The results may *seem* the same in our *example*, but make your promises only resolve after 10 seconds, and you'll notice the difference.

Comment: They don't do the same thing. The promises are never resolved in the first version.

Comment: @JJJ, even more: no promises are *created* in the first version with `new Promise`.

Comment: `As you can see, both (with and without parentheses) return the same result` that's your main mistake, in thinking you're getting the same results, you aren't even accessing the results in `.then` so, how can you claim that the results are the same

Comment: Your question is highly unclear. The results you get are completely different, yet you claim that the result ist the same.

Comment: I think he meant the result of the "program execution" which is the same indeed. It prints to the console the same message. However, in the context of using a promise the result of the promise are different indeed.

Answer (score 5):

This is the difference:

- On the first `Promise.all` you are passing a reference to a `function`.
- On the second `Promise.all` you are passing a reference to a
  `Promise`.

If you want to log the result you will see the difference:

```js
let cleanRoom = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('Cleaned The Room');
  });
};

let removeGarbage = function(message) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(message + ' remove Garbage');
  });
};

let winIcecream = function(message) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve( message + ' won Icecream');
  });
};

Promise.all([cleanRoom, removeGarbage, winIcecream]).then(function(result){
 console.log(result);
})

Promise.all([cleanRoom(), removeGarbage('foo'), winIcecream('bar')]).then(function(result){
 console.log(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention, in some of your functions you expect to get a `message` parameter.
Well, you can't pass it without using parentheses.

Comment: @Martin AJ is the above answers your question?